# In Java, why does System.out.println("\" \\"); gives " \ as output

Tags: java

In Java when i run `System.out.println("\" \\");`
I get output as :

" \

Can you please explain in detail, why this is happening?

Comment: The \ is an escape character.  It means take the next character literally not as Java syntax. If you remove the outer quotes and the \ s you have `" \ ` inside the String.

Answer (score 4):

Because you escape double quotes (`""`) with a backslash (`\`) and also a backslash with a backslash.

Answer (score 4):

`backslash` is a special character in JAVA and many other programming languages, one of its use is to escape characters in certain situation.

For example:

If you want to print a string containing double quotes like: `How are you "Bob" ?`
Printing this using `System.out.println("How are you "Bob" ?");` will not work because you are closing the quotes just before the word `Bob`. Therefore, a character was used to deal with such situation so one can print double quotes inside a string:

```
System.out.println("How are you \"Bob\" ?");
```

Moreover, since we've agreed above that `\` escapes the double quotes, if you want to print a single `backslash` inside a string, doing this `System.out.println("\");` will open the string but will escape the second double quotes which will result in an error because the string was not closed. To fix this, you need to escape the `backslash` like this: System.out.println("\");

Other interesting uses of `\`:

`\n` character to return to a new line
`\t` character to insert a tab

More about escape character can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println("\" \");  
System.out.println("   --> String Open
                   \"  --> Double Quote character escaped using backslash
                   \\  --> Backslash itself as a character escaped using backslash
                   "); --> String Close
```

will give you output as `"\`

For the list of escaped characters, You can find that [here.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

- `\t`    Insert a tab in the text at this point.
- `\b`    Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
- `\n`    Insert a newline in the text at this point.
- `\r`    Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
- `\f`    Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
- `\'`    Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
- `\"`    Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
- `\\`    Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are escaping two characters,

```
String s = "\" \\";
```

uses the single back-slash to escape first the double quote and then a backslash. So you get,

```
" \
```

You might also try

```
System.out.println(s.length());
```

Which would tell you "3". Because you have a String of '"', ' ' and '\'

Escape Sequences are explained in [The Java Tutorial: Characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), which also allows Unicode characters,

```
System.out.println("\u03A9");
```

Will output a one character String that equals

```
 Ω
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to comments of my precursors, you can check it in Oracle's Java Tutorial, list of escape sequences.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you put a `\` before a special character in java, `\` tells the `JVM` that it is not a special character, rather it is a part of a String.
So in your case, when you put a `\` before `"` , it prints a double `quote(")` and when you again put `\\` , it prints a `slash (\)`.
If you want to know more about this, you can go through the inside of Java and how the special characters are handled in java.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

These are called escape sequences. All the escape sequences start with \ (backward slash) character (e.g., \n, \t etc.,). Here \n, \t has special meaning to Java like line break and tab space respectively.  Similarly " (double quote) has a special meaning saying that termination of string literals in Java.  Instead of making " as a string literal terminator, we need to tell java compiler to treat it as a special sequence.  Hence we use these escape sequences like \\ (for backward slash), \' (single quote), \r (carriage return) etc.,

Thanks,
JK

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition according to oracle is as follows:
A character preceded by a backslash `\` is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.The following table shows the Java escape sequences

EscapeSequence      Description

1. `\"`               Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
2. `\\`             Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

By following the above description in our case for `System.out.println("\" \\")`,
`\"` would be replaced with  a double  " quote character and
`\\` would be replaced with  a (single backslash) `\` character.

Hence output printed will be `" \`

Hope this helps.